# EF Core 2.0 When property is calculated based on list of entities it requires two SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Parent has a property `LastChildrenName` and a list of the childrens.

```
parent.Children.Add(new Children(){ Name = "FirstChild" };
parent.Children.Add(new Children(){ Name = "SecondChild" };
parent.Children.Add(new Children(){ Name = "ThirdChild" };

DbContext.Set<Parent>.Update(parent);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

During debugging before first call of SaveChanges() the `LastChildrenName` has a proper value of `ThirdChild` however after `SaveChanges()` only new Children row appears in the db and the `LastChildrenName` column has value  `SecondChild`.

Calling again `SaveChanges()` right after, in the next line of code causes that parent's column `LastChildrenName` is updated with proper value.

But it also causes rising the update trigger twice on the Parent table which I want to avoid.

Am I missing an EF Core setting or a way which can be used on Parent model to update in the db only once? 
I would like also to avoid changing the `get` method of LastChildrenName property.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id;
    public ICollection<Children> Childrens {get;set;}

    public string LastChildrenName => this.Childrens.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.Name).LastOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
}
```

Children model:

```
public class Children 
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public Parent Parent;
}
```

Comment: I think you can remove `x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)`

Comment: It *doesn't*. It doens't need `DbContext.Set<Parent>.Update(parent);` either. Post your *full* code. Are you trying to reattach a detached entity? How was `parent` loaded? Why the call to *Update* or even `DbSet<Parent>`? Post your full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderBy(x => x.Id)` orders children by ID, but before the children are saved to the database, they don't have a known ID yet. Therefore, to take the simple case first, if `FirstChild` and `SecondChild` are already saved with IDs `1` and `2`, and your `ThirdChild` is added to the context but not saved yet, that third child will be seen as having ID `0`, so it would make sense that `SecondChild` is still seen as having the highest ID.

If you only ever add one child at a time, you can modify your `OrderBy` so that `0` will always appear last. You can, for instance, write `OrderBy(x => x.Id == 0).ThenBy(x => x)`.

If you add multiple children at the same time, I don't think this is going to work at all, because there is no guarantee that entities will be saved to the database in any particular order. You'd need to switch to generating IDs on the client rather than on the server to let that approach work. Alternatively, you might add a creation date/time and order by that instead.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't thought about the id = 0. Thank you!